# Emacs: Finding all commands with this or that in their names

Tags: regex, emacs, pattern-matching, apropos

Is there a way to search through all the registered commands in emacs, along with their names? For example, can I find all emacs commands with "kill" in their name?

I cannot find a list of all of emacs commands, [this](http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~vasily/idl/emacs_commands_list.html) comes the closest but does not have the names of each command, only the keybindings. However, this method requires browsing the web, an inbuilt glossary of emacs commands would be preferred...

Comment: ok, apparently googling any variation of "emacs search all commands" or "emacs command list" doesn't yield anything, but I randomly googled "emacs help" and found it...the command is `C-h a <topics>`, which "This searches for commands whose names match the argument topics. The argument can be a keyword, a list of keywords, or a regular expression"

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `apropos-command`:

```
C-h a kill RET
```

There are analoguous commands `apropos-variable` and `apropos` (which searches for commands, functions and variables).

Answer (score 1):

As @jch said, and as you found by googling: `apropos-command` is your friend. Likewise, the other `apropos*` commands. But that's just the beginning of Emacs apropos help.

If you use library [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) then each time you are prompted for the name of a command, function, variable, face, buffer, file,...*whatever*, you have built-in, incremental, *apropos* help.

That is, **Icicles** completion of such a name lets you use a regexp or a substring, not just a prefix, pattern - always.  This [*apropos completion*](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions) is the single most useful **Icicles** feature.

In addition, you can use multiple patterns to filter the matching candidates. It is a *lot* easier to use two or more simple patterns than it is to try to come up with a complex regexp that gives you the same set of matches.  This is [*progressive completion*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion).

Finally, **Icicles** gives you [*other apropos features*](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos) as well. It enhances vanilla apropos commands, provides additional apropos commands, and gives you *help on each completion candidate* - both short, mode-line descriptions (what the `apropos*` commands give you) and complete doc strings on demand.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, I'll check it out